# Comparing columns of two files

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm a new C programmer. 
I have got the situation when I have two files. First file has 4 columns and the second file has 2 columns. I need to compare 3rd column of the first file with the first column of the second file. I am looking for efficient C code. Do I have to convert the file into an array? How can I do that?

This is my part of code where I tried to convert a 3rd column into an array but it does not work because of incompatible types:

```
int countlines = 0;
char names[countlines][100];
double column1;
char column2[15];
char column3[15];
int column4;

while(!feof(pack)) {
    fscanf(pack, "%lf %s %s %i\n", &column1, column2, column3, &column4);
    names[countlines] = column3;
    countlines++;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: @WilliamPursell - I doubt if he is asking about the feof issue - his program has to compile first to hit the feof issue.

Comment: user93353 You are correct, the `feof` issue is not the root of the problem.  Are you suggesting that we should let a confessed newbie to the language perpetuate an error simply because that particular mistake was not asked about?  That seems foolish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 char names[countlines][100];
```

Like this , assuming you have maximum of 50 lines in your file.

```
#define MAX_LINES 50

char names[MAX_LINES][100];
```

Make sure that after `fscanf(pack, "%lf %s %s %i\n", &column1, column2, column3, &column4);`     this statement

conform respected variables values by printing them. and if those or fine then  use `strcpy()`  to copy strings.

```
strcpy(names[countlines], column3);
countlines++;  
    or 
strcpy(names[countlines++], column3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For column 3 now it works.
But when I try to strcpy int column4 to int ARRAY[MAX_LINES][10] it gives me: passing argument from incompatible pointer type.

Comment: @user2758935   if you want to store integers you just need array of integers.declaration : **int array[MAX_LINES];**  and usage **array[countlines++]=column4;** and array[MAX_LINES][10] is two dimentional array, this is not required in your case. where as names[MAX_LINES][100]; is required because you need to store the array of strings , where each string is array of characters.